# How to represent Highcharts data from a bean property

Tags: jsf, highcharts

I need to build a [Highcharts pie chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) with data from a Java backing bean in a JSF page.

I need to know what must be passed as the `data` attribute of `series`:

```js
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],
            {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 12.8,
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            },
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
}]
```

I suppose it's an array of arrays. Tried passing `Map<String, Double>`, `List<Map<String, Double>>`, `Map<List<String>,List<Double>>`. The last try was the list of maps (this code is inside a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` so it's executed after the constructor:

```java
    this.mapPie = new HashMap<>();
    this.mapPie.put("Column 1", 3.0);
    this.mapPie.put("Column 2", 8.5);
    this.mapPie.put("Column 3", 6.0);
    this.mapPie.put("Column 4", 15.0);
    this.mapPie.put("Column 5", 9.0);
    this.mapPie.put("Column 6", 6.5);

    this.listMapPie = new ArrayList<>();
    mapPie.entrySet().stream().forEach((Map.Entry<String, Double> pairs) -> {
        String key = pairs.getKey();
        Double value = pairs.getValue();
        Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put(key, value);
        this.listMapPie.add(m);
    });
```

All getters and setters were created, but none of those objects work and a page reload happens.

XHTML:

```xhtml
    <h:form>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-extlink" value="Pie" onclick="gerarGraficoPizza('title', 'seriesName', #{chartBean.listMapPie})">
                <p:ajax event="click" update="pie" />
            </p:commandButton>
            <div jsf:id="pie" id="pie" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

JavaScript:

```js
        //<![CDATA[
        function gerarGraficoPizza(title, seriesName, seriesData) {
            $('#pie').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: 1, //null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: title
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                        type: 'pie',
                        name: seriesName,
                        data: seriesData
                    }]
            });
        }
        //]]>
```

EDIT:

Modified the Java code and now the list of maps was filled, but same result in the page:

```
        this.listMapPie = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mapPie = new HashMap<>();
        this.mapPie.put("Column 1", 3.0);
        this.listMapPie.add(this.mapPie);
        this.mapPie = new HashMap<>();
        this.mapPie.put("Column 2", 8.5);
        this.listMapPie.add(this.mapPie);
        this.mapPie = new HashMap<>();
        this.mapPie.put("Column 3", 6.0);
        this.listMapPie.add(this.mapPie);
        this.mapPie = new HashMap<>();
        this.mapPie.put("Column 4", 15.0);
        this.listMapPie.add(this.mapPie);
        this.mapPie = new HashMap<>();
        this.mapPie.put("Column 5", 9.0);
        this.listMapPie.add(this.mapPie);
        this.mapPie = new HashMap<>();
        this.mapPie.put("Column 6", 6.5);
        this.listMapPie.add(this.mapPie);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's [JSON format](http://json.org). You're trying to pass `List#toString()` and `Map#toString()` as if it's already JSON format. This isn't right. You need a JSON printer. At bottom of [json.org](http://json.org) page you can find several JSON APIs which supports both parsing and printing. One of them is [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Install it (just put JAR in webapp's runtime classpath, usually by dropping in `/WEB-INF/lib`).

Once done that, just do

```
listMapPieAsJson = new Gson().toJson(listMapPie);
```

```html
onclick="gerarGraficoPizza('title', 'seriesName', #{chartBean.listMapPieAsJson})"
```

As to the format of `listMapPie`, you were close. The supported formats are just listed in [their documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data). Let's assume that you want an array of objects with named values (which is way 3 as shown in documentation). In order to achieve the desired JSON format from Java side on, you only need to know those 2 rules:

1. `[]` is an array in JSON and can in Java be presented by `List<T>` or `T[]`.
2. `{}` is an object in JSON and can in Java be presented by `Map<K, V>` or a `Bean` which is a true Javabean class with getters/setters.

Your mistake was that you used the column name directly as map key instead of setting it along with `name` as key.

```
listMapPie = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Object> mapPie;

mapPie = new HashMap<>();
mapPie.put("name", "Column 1")
mapPie.put("y", 3.0);
listMapPie.add(mapPie);

mapPie = new HashMap<>();
mapPie.put("name", "Column 2")
mapPie.put("y", 8.5);
listMapPie.add(mapPie);

mapPie = new HashMap<>();
mapPie.put("name", "Column 3")
mapPie.put("y", 6.0);
listMapPie.add(mapPie);

// Etc..

listMapPieAsJson = new Gson().toJson(listMapPie);
```

An alternative is to create a simple Javabean class:

```
public class Pie {
    private String name;
    private double y;
    // Add/generate c'tors/getters/setters/equals/hashCode.
}
```

So that you can just do

```
listMapPie = new ArrayList<>();
listMapPie.add(new Pie("Column 1", 3.0));
listMapPie.add(new Pie("Column 2", 8.5));
listMapPie.add(new Pie("Column 3", 6.0));
// Etc..
listMapPieAsJson = new Gson().toJson(listMapPie);
```